# I have been shortlisted for a professor position in Germany (ranked 3 out of 4). What chances do I have to be offered the position?

Tags: professorship, faculty-application, germany, negotiation

I recently got to know that I am third in a shortlist of four candidates for a full professor position in a German university.
I am not that experienced about German academia, since I worked in other countries, so far.

Unofficially, I have been told that the first candidate, who is already a full professor, quite likely is not really interested in the position, but rather she/he is trying to negotiate better conditions in her/his current university.
I have no info about the second candidate. In case also this second candidate does not accept the job, I would be invited to the negotiation.

According to your experience, what are the chances that candidates, who are not in the top positions of the shortlist, can access the negotiation? In other words, what are the chances that top candidates leave the position to lower-ranked candidates, for any reason?

I have been told that anything could happen, even that none of the shortlisted candidates accepts the position (well, actually *I would accept*). But I have no clues about statistics. How likely is, according to your experience, that I will be invited to the negotiation? Having a hint would be very useful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: very very slim, but it happens many times that first two think they are Gods and can request anything

Comment: Thanks, this is also my impression. How would you rate your "many times": 5% of cases, 10% ... ?

Comment: Currently there is a pandemic and universities are experiencing financial difficulties.  Therefore people are very unlikely to turn down offers.  I'd rate your chances very low.

Comment: I am confused about why you would be told such a thing.

Comment: That renegotiation game is relatively common, but how it will end up is anybodies guess. If the old university of the first candidate doesn't want to make a good offer, he might still take the new one. And if they didn't tell you anything about the second candidate he's much more likely to not have a permanent position yet, so he'll likely take it.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist German universities are almost all publicly funded and a lot of that funding is long term and cannot be changed so easily. Some of it is even dependent on the number of students, which usually rises in recessions. So the only financial difficulties would be in fields like engineering which are more strongly dependent on third-party funds.

Comment: @mlk Number of students is not increasing now.  International enrollments have fallen a lot.  Students who do not like online learning are not enrolling.  It's not 2008.

Comment: @mlk I have the impression you are quite experienced with the German academia, thanks for commenting. Actually I have been told that the second candidate is not tenured (same as me). So I guess the chances s/he takes the job are quite high... Any previous experience when the 3rd or even 4th in the list got the job?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist not case for germany, in some weird way of financing, recession are good for German universities

Comment: @Joss21 Some discipline, dont know yours, professors have god complex and even ask for spouse hire. depend on the field

Comment: @Joss21 Being a part of German academia gives you that experience. Sadly though my experience with professorial appointments is only second hand. I've talked about it with people who applied and gotten the job (i.e. German professors) and I've talked with people who have been part of a committee, but I have had no direct experience myself yet. I also don't have any good statistics, so that is why I don't feel qualified to post a proper answer.